# Renown vs. renowned

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct? 'The event will be held in the renown abbey' OR 'the event will be held in the renowned abbey' ?

Comment: You can look in a dictionary for "renown" and "renowned" and get your answer (which will be "renowned").

Answer (score 4):

[Renowned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renowned) is an adjective, meaning *widely acclaimed*:

> The event will be held in the renowned abbey.

[Renown](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renown) is a noun, meaning *great fame*:

> The abbey is of some renown.

Answer (score 2):

Renowned is the correct word to use in this sentence. You are describing the abbey, and it is renowned.